# Mock a dependancy within a dependancy with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I need to test this function:

```
import dependency from 'dependency';

export default values => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(dependency(values));
  // More code
};
```

Ive got a test which asserts that `dispatch` called `dependency`:

```
import functionToTest from 'function-to-test';

jest.mock('dependency', () => () => 'dependency res');

describe('functionToTest', () => {
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    functionToTest({ foo: 'bar' })(dispatch);

    test('test', () => {
        expect(dispatch.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('dependency res');
    });
});
```

I need to assert that `dependancy` was called with `{ foo: 'bar' }`. I tried naming my dependancy mock but when I `console.log` it it's undefined:

```
import functionToTest from 'function-to-test';

const dependencyMock = jest.mock('dependency', () => () => 'dependency res');

describe('functionToTest', () => {
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    functionToTest({ foo: 'bar' })(dispatch);

    test('test', () => {
        expect(dispatch.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('dependency res');

        console.log(dependencyMock.mock.calls) // undefined
    });
});
```

I attempted to create a new jest function `spy` hoping that I could inspect it's arguments, but this returned an error

```
import functionToTest from 'function-to-test';

const spy = jest.fn(() => 'save-form-data');

const dependencyMock = jest.mock('dependency', () => spy);

describe('functionToTest', () => {
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    functionToTest({ foo: 'bar' })(dispatch);

    test('test', () => {
        expect(dispatch.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('dependency res');

        console.log(dependencyMock.mock.calls) // undefined
    });
});
```

> The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any
>   out-of-scope variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close!

You need to move the mock function inside the module factory function passed to `jest.mock`.

Then you just need to import `dependency` into the test and check that it was called as expected:

```js
import functionToTest from 'function-to-test';
import dependency from 'dependency';  // <= dependency will be...

jest.mock('dependency', () =>
  jest.fn(() => 'dependency res')  // <= ...this mock function
);

describe('functionToTest', () => {
  it('should dispatch dependency', () => {
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    functionToTest({ foo: 'bar' })(dispatch);

    expect(dispatch.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('dependency res');  // Success!
    expect(dependency).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ foo: 'bar' });  // Success!
  });
});
```

Note that by default `babel-jest` hoists `jest.mock` calls and they run before anything else in the test file, so module factory functions passed to `jest.mock` have to be completely self-contained.